# 3 way optional relations in rails through a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm struggling to get my head around a join table that I need to implement.

I have three models, FitnessProgram, Workout and Phase.

FitnessPrograms can have many Workouts that do not belong to a Phase or have many Phases (i.e. week 1) that have many Workouts.

So Phases are optional, I'm using a join table called FitnessProgramWorkouts to connect the three models

```
FitnessProgramWorkouts
  belongs_to :fitness_program
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :phase
FitnessProgram
  has_many :fitness_program_workouts
  has_many :phases, through: :fitness_program_workouts
  has_many :workouts, through: :fitness_program_workouts
Phase
  has_many :fitness_program_workouts
  has_one  :program, through: :fitness_program_workouts
  has_many :workouts, through: :fitness_program_workouts
Workouts
  has_many :fitness_program_workouts
  has_one  :program, through: :fitness_program_workouts
  has_many :phases, through: :fitness_program_workouts
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Does each workout belong to exactly one phase or fitness program, or are the workouts reused between programs and phases?

Comment: Depending on context, you might find it simpler to simply have a `Phase` placeholder record for workouts without a phase, and use a `has_many: through:` setup for Program > Phase > Workouts.

Comment: I agree with Jake; it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Workout can belong to one program but can be in multiple phases